# Android APK expansion file won't download

Tags: android, download, expansion

I have a big issue with the download of an apk expansion file. I have read the tutorial http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html
and copied the code from the sample. I uploaded everything on the developer console.
Also the download won't work. I don't get any error messages. The app starts, the download view appears and nothing else happens.
I also tried to debug the app. But all I see is that the App gets the response "NO_DOWNLOAD_REQUIRED" also the file is definitely not available on the device.

**EDIT:** I just see that when I delete the app and make a fresh build I get the status message "XAPK File Validation Failed". But only for the first start, after that nothing happens.
Could it be that the filesize has to be exact?

```
private static final XAPKFile[] xAPKS = {
            new XAPKFile(
                    true, 
                    1, 
                    508443334L 
            )        
    };
```

If so how do I get the exact size?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, define exact filesize of obb archive is one of requirements for using expansion APK file.

For windows: open cmd -> move to folder with expansion file -> type "dir" command[image]